# How to bind Combobox to a command in ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox, system.reactive, reactiveui

I was wondering what is the best way to bind the control properties to the CommandParameter in ReactiveUI?

The `BindCommand` below does not provide a way to pass the parameter. The overload either takes a `property in view model` or an `IObservable<T>` for parameters.

**View**

```cs
this.WhenActivated(subscription =>
{
    subscription(this.BindCommand(
                    this.ViewModel,
                    vm => vm.TextCommand,
                    v => v.ComboBox
                    ));
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ReactiveCommand<string, Unit> TextCommand { get; set; }


    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        TextCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string>(DoSomething);

    }

    private Task DoSomething(string selectedText)
    {
        return Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

The DoSomething method is called with selectedText as `null` everytime.

I have tried passing the `IObservable` for ToggleSwitch, but the behaviour is not as expected.

**View**

```cs
IObservable<bool> toggleOn = this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.Toggle.IsOn);
this.WhenActivated(subscription =>
{
     subscription(this.BindCommand(
                this.ViewModel,
                vm => vm.ToggleCommand,
                v => v.Toggle, toggleOn));
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
ToggleCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<bool>(Toggled);

private Task Toggled(bool toggleState)
{
   return Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

In the above code I do managed to get the `toggleState`, but it is the last state not the new state of the ToggleSwitch. Also, I could not make this work of ComboBox. I think it is a very common to pass command parameters from view and there should be an easier way to achieve it. What am I missing? I am using UWP app.

Thanks

Comment: Combobox's don't inheritantly have a "Command" though normally, is it you are attempting to trigger a command on the selected value changing?

Comment: You may be right, but the Command works as advertised. Whenever I change the selection in `ComboBox` or `ToggleSwitch` the command is executed. The question is how to pass a parameter to that command that is a property of a control, in the case of `ComboBox` it may be `SelectedItem` or in `ToggleSwitch` `IsOn`.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to do a Binding to a property in your VM to the SelectedItem, then you can have a WhenAnyValue(x => x....).InvokeCommand() instead. Then you got full access to your property. That is if you need the Command due to a Task/Observable you need to await upon.

Comment: This looks like an acceptable way out. Let me try it

Comment: This worked but had some side effects (maybe to do with my limited knowledge). `this.Bind(this.ViewModel,
                    vm => vm.SelectedValue,
                    v => v.ComboBox.SelectedValue)` leaks the `ComboBoxItem` in the view model. Only if there is a way to select the `Content` as `string` instead of `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can only bind commands to events, not directly to properties (maybe I'm wrong).

What if you subscribe to the SelectedValueChanged (Can't remember the name of the event) event in the combobox and then fire the command manually?

```
this.ComboBox.Events().SelectedValueChanged
    .Select(_ => ComboBox.Text)
    .InvokeCommand(this, vm => vm.ViewModel.TextCommand);
```